# Apache mod_rewrite infinite loop, cannot fix it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(.*) /Application/?path=$1/$2$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ /Application/?path=ACFrontPage/getMainPage [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*) /Application/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This line causes infinite redirect:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /Application/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I need if previous rules didn't match, to redirect everything to index.php file. 
How can I do it?

From logs its doing this:

```
split uri=/Application/?path=Application/ -> uri=/Application/, args=path=Application/&path=Application/&path=Application/&path=Application/&path=Application/&path=Application/&path=Application/&path=Application/&path=Application/&path=Application/
```

========================

@anubhava

I tried your suggested answer and it works for everything except base domain i.e.:
http://example.com/

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Application/index\.php` above `RewriteRule (.*) /Application/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]`  or `RewriteRule ((?!^/Application/index\.php).*) /Application/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]` - did not check it

Comment: Thanks, first one i tried, it didn't work out for me, second one i will try later.

Comment: Oh sorry first one actually worked. thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule`. Tweak your rules to avoid rewrites for all existing file or directories:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /Application/?path=ACFrontPage/getMainPage [L]

# skip rewrite for all files/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(.*)$ /Application/?path=$1/$2$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /Application/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Tried it as suggested didn't help.

Comment: Those type of comments don't help much. Provide details as what is location of this .htaccess? What URL did you enter in browser? What error did you get and are there more rules also?

Comment: Sorry, i just used the solution that was suggested in comments to my question. As for the info you ask for, i will edit my question with it.

Comment: Tested it more carefully it works for everything except base domain.

Comment: ok what happens when you enter: `http://example.com/`? Do you get 404 page? As per above rules it show content of `http://example.com//Application/?path=ACFrontPage/getMainPage`

Comment: With this http://example.com//Application/?path=ACFrontPage/getMainPage - Page is displayed correctly but when you use: example.com/ it gives: 403 Error.

Comment: There is no rule to cause 403 anywhere. Try adding `Options +All -MultiViews` on top of your .htaccess

Comment: Options +All -MultiViews on top of htaccess causes internal server error 500: .htaccess: Option MultiViews not allowed here. The 403 on main page seems to be caused by the fact that no rules are applied for it. When i disable htaccess i get same error, but if i enable it and add index.html in home directory, that file is shown

Comment: You need to have `Options All` line in your Apache config for this. What is your Apache version?

Comment: Apache 2.2, Not sure I am ready to allow multiview option. how is solution suggest by you better then just filtering query as suggested above? RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Application/
RewriteRule (.*) /Application/?path=$1 [L,QSA] - it works just fine for current conditions.

Comment: It is better due to `# skip rewrite for all files/directories` rule which skips rewriting for not just for `/Application/index.php` bot all the files and directories.

Comment: In any case there is no rule here that can cause 403 so you seem to have some rule/code that you need to find

Comment: 403 is caused because there is no file to run in home directory. And seems that RewriteRule ^$ /Application/?path=ACFrontPage/getMainPage [L] is not applied when i add file to home directory, i see its contents on home page.. =

Comment: If i do it like this then it works:   `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /Application/?path=ACFrontPage/getMainPage [L]

# skip rewrite for all files/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(.*)$ /Application/?path=$1/$2$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /Application/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: You have to arrange your answer as i explained, then i will be able to accept it.